# Lua Console For Webdesign?

Tags: javascript, testing, command-line, console, lua

I have learned to use Lua a lot of the time and I also use JavaScript.
But I find that JavaScript is harder for me to read and write.

Recently I started testing web-pages.

I don't mind using JavaScript to test pages and some of their functions (though there are libraries, I prefer testing with commands).

Is there any Lua console app/plugin/extension for Chrome or Firefox that runs Lua and gives access to the DOM?

Comment: Do you want to externally control the browser using lua as a command language? or run lua in the browser - if the second http://luakit.org/projects/luakit/ is around - never tried it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[luajs](https://github.com/mherkender/lua.js) converts lua to javascript.